# Como hacer para que al re-direcionar a la pagina me salga un mensaje?

Tags: python, django

mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para que si un registro es insertado correctamente , al redirecionarme me muestre el mensaje de registro insertado correctamente.

Esta es la vista que me redirecciona:

```
@login_required()
def inventarioempaque(request):
    empaque = Empaque.objects.all().order_by('fecha' , 'celda')
    for obj in empaque:
        delta = fecha_actual - obj.fecha
        obj.dias_desde_registro = delta.days
    #Codigo que retorna la plantilla home y llama el diccionario context
    return render(request,"inventario/empaque/empaque.html",{'empaque': empaque});
```

Esta es la vista que agrega el producto:

```
def inventarioingresoe(request):
    empaque = Empaque.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        variedad = request.POST["variedad"]
        empaque = request.POST["empaque"]
        grado = request.POST["grado"]
        comercializadora = request.POST["comercializadora"]
        ramos = request.POST["ramos"]
        unidades = request.POST["unidades"]
        celda = request.POST["celda"]
        if Empaque.objects.filter(celda=celda):
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'valido': False}))
        else:
            nuevoingreso = Empaque.objects.create( fecha = fecha,
                                                   hora = hora,
                                                   variedad = variedad,
                                                   empaque = empaque,
                                                   grado = grado,
                                                   comercializadora = comercializadora,
                                                   ramos = ramos,
                                                   unidades = unidades,
                                                   total = int(unidades) * int(ramos),
                                                   celda = celda)
            return redirect('empaque')

    return render(request,"inventario/empaque/ingresoe.html", {})
```

Estas son mis url:

```
url(r'inventario/empaque/', SGregorio_views.inventarioempaque, name='empaque'),
    url(r'^inventario/ingreso/$', SGregorio_views.inventarioingresoe, name='empaqueingreso'),
```

Alguien que me ayude por favor.

Comment: ¿Algo como esto https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/contrib/messages/?

Comment: No lo que pasa es que si el registro ingresa correctamente me redirecciona a la pagina donde muestra todos lo registros lo que quiero es que cuando me redireccione a esa pagina me muestre un mensaje de éxito ingresando registro o algo así.

Answer (score 1):

Al momento de guardar tu registro, puedes usar Django Messages:

En tus views.py

```
...
# En la parte donde haces tus imports
from django.contrib import messages


# al momento de guardar tu modelo
   ...
       nuevoingreso = Empaque.objects.create(
           fecha=fecha, hora=hora, variedad=variedad,
           empaque=empaque, grado=grado,
           comercializadora=comercializadora,
           ramos=ramos, unidades=unidades,
           total=int(unidades) * int(ramos), celda=celda
       )
       # simplemente agregas esta linea de código
       messages.succes(request, 'se ha creado el empaque exitosamente')
   ...
...
```

Ya solo queda en tu template en el cual quieres recibir el mensaje agregar algo como esto, (debes ubicarlo en el lugar donde quieres que se vea el mensaje), recuerda que es el template a donde harás la redirección, si lo haces en el otro, no podrás verlo

template.html

```
...
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="row">
           <div class="alert {% if message.tags == "success" %}alert-success {% else %}alert-danger{% endif %} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
              <button class="close" aria-label="close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">x</span></button>
               <p>{{ message|safe }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
...
```

Comment: gracias pero no es lo que necesito lo que necesito es hacer una consulta en la base de datos y obtener una respuesta sin la necesidad de redirecionar la pagina.

Comment: ¿que consulta?, he leido nuevamente el post, y las otras respuestas y comentarios, y basicamente lo que quieres es lo que te puse en mi respuesta... No estoy seguro si es que ya lo llegaste a probar, o por favor sé mas especifica diciendo que quieres hacer

Comment: Hola mira es que si yo agrego un registro y se agrega bien me redireciona a un templete donde muestro todos mis registros y este template ya tiene una vista propia.